# How add extra middleware in grup route?

Tags: laravel-5

I create admin panel and want give access to some role like admin, mod, support, god etc. But in the same group one of route i would like give access only for God and Admin. Can i do this in one group or should i create separate group for this route (separate group or add middleware to one route only) but i prefer separate group.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['roles'], 'roles' => ['administrator', 'moderator', 'support']], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
        Route::get('users', 'AdminController@users')->name('admin.users');
        Route::get('messages', 'AdminController@messages')->name('admin.messages');    
    });
```

And separate group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['roles'], 'roles' => ['administrator']], function () {
        Route::get('finance', 'AdminController@finance')->name('admin.finance');
    });
```

How can i do in one group. I tried but i have access all the to the finance method even if i am support only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work as separate groups, as Laravel will apply all the middleware requirements to routes in the group in one go.

The other option is to use nested groups (if appropriate), but this would essentially be the same as separate groups:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['roles'], 'roles' => ['administrator', 'moderator', 'support']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
    Route::get('users', 'AdminController@users')->name('admin.users');
    Route::get('messages', 'AdminController@messages')->name('admin.messages');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['roles'], 'roles' => ['administrator']], function () {
        Route::get('finance', 'AdminController@finance')->name('admin.finance');
    });
});
```